# Docker - build an environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

After hours of googling I just can't find what I am looking for.

I want to know if I can do the following with Docker: have separate Docker files that can be deployed and shared among a group of devs in my team.

For example:

- Container 1 - install of lumen that can also have react installed along with it via command line. Most of our projects are lumen with some needing react/typescript installing too. (being able to use npm install too)
- Container 2 - MYSQL/MariaDB with or without data. I understand you could have data in a separate container. I don't mind having MySQL etc in container 1 if I can have the data separate.

The idea is that container 1 can be swapped out as they will represent different projects but the DB data can be a separate container so we can all have our own copy of container 2 and if for whatever reason it get corrupt. we can just re use it.

Answer (score 1):

In Docker, you have different object:
- Dockerfile, it's a file used for building an image
- Image, it's the result of a build using an image definition like a Dockerfile
- Container, it's basically a running image
- Registry, a place where you can store images and share them with other people

So, for your use case, you have different solution, but if I understand your needs, you want to share an image containing lumen and some npm packages to your team? If it's the case, you could build it and push it in a registry.

Your team could use it as is or build custom image based on this one.

For your mysql/mariadb container, you could use the base image and add initialization script (sql or sh files) in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

If you screw the database, you could only remove the container and its volume and start it again.

Comment: So based on this and the research I have done.. i would need to create a container with my base lumen install and packages (such as php, nginx, react/typescript), save that as an image. then build an image for MYSQL as a base then add an intialzation script. If i run both containers at the same time, will it automatically allow me to connect to the DB container?

Comment: For MySQL, you could build your custom image based on the mysql base image: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql
And for the base lumen install, you need to create a Dockerfile yes and build it (`docker build <user>/<image_name>` and share it (`docker push <user>/<image_name>`).